# Need to convert an array to a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I was given data to import and it imported as an array but I need it as a dictionary. It essentially imports as a dictionary just within an array and I don't know how to make it just an array.

I have tried replacing the '[' with ' ' but this hasn't worked and I'm sure theres a better way

I imported the data this way

```
stock = np.loadtxt("wh_stock.dat",dtype = dict)
```

Result was:

```
['{"01":' '115,' '"02":' '34,' '"03":' '350,' '"04":' '273,' '"05":'
 '922,' '"06":' '844,' '"07":' '575,' '"08":' '523,' '"09":' '179,'
 '"10":' '676,' '"11":' '825,' '"12":' '693,' '"13":' '632,' '"14":'
 '195,' '"15":' '692,' '"16":' '956,' '"17":' '619,' '"18":' '588,'
 '"19":' '580,' '"20":' '648}']
```

I want it to be:

```
 {"01": 115, "02": 34, "03": 350, "04": 273, "05":
     922, "06": 844, "07": 575, "08": 523, "09": 179,
     "10": 676, "11": 825, "12": 693, "13": 632, "14":
     195, "15": 692, "16": 956, "17": 619, "18": 588,
     "19": 580, "20": 648}
```

Original data in .dat file:

{"01": 115, "02": 34, "03": 350, "04": 273, "05":
         922, "06": 844, "07": 575, "08": 523, "09": 179,
         "10": 676, "11": 825, "12": 693, "13": 632, "14":
         195, "15": 692, "16": 956, "17": 619, "18": 588,
         "19": 580, "20": 648}
there is probably a better way to import but this is all I have been taught

Comment: `stock = np.loadtxt("wh_stock.dat",dtype = str)[0]`. That will be a string of a dict that you'll need `ast.literal_eval` for. Numpy won't work well with dicts anyway so I'm not sure why this ever came into being

Comment: You don't want `{"01": 115, "02": 34, ...}`, i.e. integers for the values?

Comment: @fuglede yes I just didn't type it right

Comment: Please post the original input file.

Answer (score 2):

The python json library can help you out:

**UPDATED**

`stock` is actually being saved as a kind of space separated dataframe, *NOT* just a string (which it does look like). That being said, this is a pretty small dataset, so you can just join it together to treat it like a string:

```
import json

stock = np.loadtxt("wh_stock.dat", dtype=list)
data_str = "".join(stock)
json.loads(data_str) #json.loads will ensure its a dict object
```

additionally, if you do want integer keys as [fuglede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5085211/fuglede) pointed out, you can type cast your dict keys:

```
int_keyed_stock = {int(key): val for key, val in json.loads(data_str).items()}
```

For sure not the most elegant solution, and im sure pandas can handle this better, but the dataset you have is tiny, so no need to go overboard

Comment: I get this error: Expecting value: line 1 column 7 (char 6)

Comment: I see the problem, the output of the loadtxt function is not just a string inside a list (which at first I thought is what it was), but a space separated series of strings, sort of a weird small dataframe (I'm not that familiar with this function). So joining it together like i illustrated above will let you manipulate it better

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify structural type of data and formats in loadtxt function.
'|S4' means 4-byte string.

```
a = np.loadtxt(d, dtype={'names': ('key', 'val'), 'formats':('|S4', np.int32)})
b = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0].decode('utf-8'), x[1]), a))
```

The first line will load the strings as byte data, e.g b'02', you can turn them into regular string type with decode function which takes a character set encoding.

Comment: when i try this I get an error of 'could not convert string to float: '115,''